# Memory efficient serialization of large data structures with common elements

Tags: memory, serialization, ocaml

Assume a data structure like the following:

```
type data = A of a_struct | B 

and a_struct = { s : string ; cross : data list ; down : data list }
```

where the cross elements are basically copies from the tree consisting of the down elements. Serializing a large instance of such a tree (~ 250MB) using yojson breaks my system due to the memory usage (several GB). That is probably because json does not know about sharing the several copies in the tree. I assmume the same holds for S-Expressions.

Is there a way to serialize in a format that is closer to OCaml's internal representation or do I have to compress the data myself?

Answer (score 1):

Core's [`binprot`](https://github.com/janestreet/bin_prot) is quite efficient in space, but doesn't support sharing. As far, as I know, only `Marshal` module supports sharing, but it is not very stable, as it can change formats per different versions of compiler. If it doesn't matter for you, then it would be probably a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Marshal`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Marshal.html) module preserves sharing by default. (You can turn it off with a flag.)